langchain ollama module difference
I'm making a chatbot using langchain and Ollama inference, but after some research I see some different module import such as:
from langchain.llms.ollama import Ollama

model = Ollama(model="llama3")

another example:
from langchain_community.llms import Ollama

ollama = Ollama(model="llama3")

another example:
from langchain_ollama import ChatOllama

llm = ChatOllama(model="llama3")

another example:
from langchain.llms import Ollama

llm = Ollama(model="llama3")

and maybe there's another module that I missed
So what is the difference? And which one should I use?

From my understanding, the difference is the model's objective. Eg.
The following is specific for chat completion >
https://python.langchain.com/v0.2/docs/integrations/chat/ollama/
And this is the list of model for text completion >
https://python.langchain.com/v0.2/docs/integrations/llms/ollama/
For more details, check this > https://python.langchain.com/v0.2/docs/concepts/#llms
where explains

Pure text-in/text-out LLMs tend to be older or lower-level. Many popular models are best used as chat completion models, even for non-chat use cases.


thanks for your answer, i read the same docs before and thats why i didnt ask about the text completion model from langchain_ollama.llms import OllamaLLM. and from the 4 examples i show before, is it all chat completion or different model?

The 1st and the 4th are the same. The latest APIs are supposed to be
from langchain_ollama import ChatOllama for chat and from langchain_ollama.llms import OllamaLLM for text
